Emailing Script Output
Regarding the amazing help received in Diskspace Report HTML Text Color Output
I'm now trying to email the output but not sure how to package it up.
Appreciate the help immensely.
I'm trying to figure it out but typical non-coder brick walls.
## Compiles the $HtmlTeplate with the values for the title date, the CSS and the disk rows.   
## because $HtmlTableRowArray is an array, it needs to be converted to a single string through -Join.  
## The resulting string is then set on the report file
$HtmlTemplate -f $titleDate, $css, ($HtmlTableRowArray -join [System.Environment]::NewLine) | Set-Content -Path $DiskReportFile

# Send Notification if alert $i is greater then 0 
if ($i -gt 0) 
{ 
    foreach ($user in $users) 
{ 
        Write-Host "Sending Email notification to $user" 
   
  $smtpServer = "10.200.200.200" 
  $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
  $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
  $msg.To.Add($user) 
        $msg.From = "disksspacereport@typicalMSP.com" 
  $msg.Subject = "Servers DiskSpace Report for $titledate" 
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
        $msg.Body = get-content $<WHAT TO PUT HERE?> - I'm guessing another variable attached to the path variable.>
  $smtp.Send($msg) 
        $body = "" 
    } 
  } 


First: use a modern module for sending mail, System.Net.Mail* is obsolete. Second: do you want to send the HTML file as a ATTACHMENT or you want it being the body of the mail?

Body of the email - the script as written fro GigHub sent it flawlessly, now I'm trying to get your updated script sent. Let me send you a 6 pack of IPA. :)
Your talent is something I'd give anything for. Code is Poetry. You're a MF Shakespeare.

If you want to use the generated HTML as message body, you just need to add its value to its Body property.
BONUS: having used HTML5 means better support from standards-following email clients and websites!
But please do check alternatives to Net.Mail
Also my code is far from great, but it seem to work so that's good enough.
# Instead of piping the result directly to the file, first save it in a variable.       
$CompiledHtml = $HtmlTemplate -f $titleDate, $css, ($HtmlTableRowArray -join [System.Environment]::NewLine)

# Then IF YOU NEED you can still save the HTML in its own file.   
# If you do not, you can skip this step.  
$CompiledHtml | Set-Content -Path $DiskReportFile

# Send Notification if there is at least one element.  
# If no elements it results $false. No need for more variables! Recycling is good even for code!  
if ($HtmlTableRowArray) { 

    <#
       If you want to create the file only if there are rows, 
       move the code about compiling the string and printing it here
    #>

    foreach ($user in $users) { 
        Write-Host "Sending Email notification to $user" 


        # Rewritten in a more modern\standardized way
        $smtpClient = [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient]::new() 
        $smtpClient.Host='10.200.200.200'

        # Rewritten in a more modern\standardized way
        $msg = [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]::new()
        $msg.To.Add($user) 
        $msg.From = 'disksspacereport@typicalMSP.com' 
        $msg.Subject = "Servers DiskSpace Report for $titledate" 
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 

        # Just use the previously created variable!   
        $msg.Body = $CompiledHtml

        # Send the message, I guess.
        $smtpClient.Send($msg) 
        
    } 
} 


Tested adding the body variable and receiving email with disk % gray instead of red/white. So the write to disk works without the new email handler. I'll create a new thread with complete code. One last try (isn't that a pop song?)

The color might be because the rendering shenanigans of your email client. It's possible it's cutting off the style part of the HTML(check the source of the mail message). The only workaround I know would be putting the CSS in-line in each element as necessary, but clients might just ignore them altogether. I suggest adding the tags for HTML, CSS and EMAIL(or something like that) for better matching answers(it doesn't seems to be a Powershell problem)
